# How to implement a generic mongodb repository with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, generics

I want to implement a generic MongoDB repository using only the mongodb-Driver and TypeScript but I'm stuck with some type issues. Here's my current code including the (shortened) TypeScript errors as comments:

```js
import type { Collection, Db, ObjectId, WithId } from 'mongodb';

export interface BaseDocument {
    _id?: ObjectId;
}

export abstract class BaseRepository<T extends BaseDocument> {
    protected readonly collection: Collection<T>;

    constructor(db: Db, collectionName: string) {
        this.collection = db.collection(collectionName);
    }

    public async findById(id: ObjectId): Promise<WithId<T> | null> {
        // No overload matches this call.
        // [...]
        return await this.collection.findOne({ _id: id });
    }

    public async save(document: T): Promise<void> {
        // Argument of type '{ _id: ObjectId | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Filter<T>'.
        // Type '{ _id: ObjectId | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in keyof WithId<T>]?: Condition<WithId<T>[P]> | undefined; }'.
        await this.collection.updateOne({ _id: document._id }, { $set: document }, { upsert: true });
    }
}
```

Do you know how to implement it correctly without typecasting the filter parameter of the findOne and updateOne method calls?